# Links Move to right on Hover in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am Styling the Navigation Links and when i hover on the link, it changes color but it moves a few pixels on right side and again becomes normal when the cursor is removed from hovering.

My Navigation CSS

```
.logo-wrapper {
  padding-bottom: 85px;
  background-color: #2e3639;

}

.logo-items{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font: "Times New Roman";
  float: left;
  margin-left: 500px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;

}

.logo-items a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-bottom:solid 1px transparent;
}

.logo-items a:hover {
  background-color: #61696c;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.logo-items span {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

My Navigation

```
<div class="logo-wrapper">
                <div class="logo-items">
                  <span>Logo</span>
                  <span>
                   <%= link_to "Tags", tags_path %>
                  </span>
                  <span>Pages</span>

                </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Well... you do have a `padding` rule on your `.logo-items a:hover` selector. Did you mean to put that on the selector without `:hover`?

Comment: You have to put `padding: 4px;` (just one value is enough because all are same values) to `.logo-items a` also.

Comment: Please post a fiddle, It's help to track real problem. And Why you put 'padding:' into ':hover' css?

Comment: I have put padding in :hover because on hovering, it should provide some room on all sides of text rather than just wrapping the text alone and then border radius to round the corners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you are getting this because you have added padding to your :hover to get your grey background effect.

```
.logo-items a:hover {
  background-color: #61696c;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

A quick way to stop the jump is to add padding to your link in the first place so the widths are allways the same

```
.logo-items a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-bottom:solid 1px transparent;
  padding:4px;
}
```

Ive added a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/domjgreen/uNKm8/

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this:-

Add "`padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;`" in "`.logo-items a{`" too... Please see the updated code:-

```
.logo-items a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-bottom:solid 1px transparent;
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}
```

Refer the Fiddle :- **http://jsfiddle.net/eETN8/**

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Either remove the `padding` on `.logo-items a:hover` or add the same `padding` to `.logo-items a`.

`padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px` is CSS shorthand for setting 4px padding (space between edge of the element and its content), but it's only applied to the hover state so that is what is causing the movement of a few pixels you're talking about.

Also, `padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;` can be shortened to `padding: 4px;` as they are the same thing.  I'm guessing you added the padding to make the background color change on hover look better, so just add `padding: 4px` to `.logo-items a` and you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

It's the problem with the border, you'd need to give border to your a before hover also to avoid the pixel movement